# Can you configure CMake to automatically install apt deb dependencies?

Tags: cmake, apt, cpack, debian-packaging

A debian package is built using CMake/CPack (CPACK_GENERATOR = "DEB")

The built package contains an executable and some shared objects.

One of the shared objects has a dependency on libjpeg.so.62, which should be installed in the system.
Is it possible to configure CMake to install libjepeg automatically via **apt**,
when my product is installed by running `sudo apt install ./my.deb`?

Comment: Use [`CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS) or the appropriate component based version.

Comment: CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS was the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And JFYI... CMake (or CPack to be precise) knows nothing about `apt` ;-) (or any other way a user might try to install a built package ;-) -- resolving dependencies is a task for the package manager. Specifying dependencies is a task for a package author/developer ;-) so CPack can produce one which going to depend on another...